# IF Statement does not work in my situation

Tags: php

```
if (isset($_POST["submit2"])) {
    $uid = $_SESSION["uid"];
    $remove_id = $_POST["remove_id"];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM orders WHERE product_id = '$remove_id' AND user_id = '$uid'";
    $run_query = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    $payment = $_POST["p_status"];
    $method = "Paypal";
    if ($payment == $method) {
        echo "Please contact the company";
    }
    else if ($run_query) {                                      
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
    }
}
```

My if statement doesnt work. it always continue to run_query.please help me thanks. `p_status` is "Paypal"

Comment: what is the result from `echo $payment` ?

Comment: the result is Paypal

Comment: well, thats weird. can i see the form before ?

Comment: `$run_query = mysqli_query($link,$sql);` is the statement that runs the query. The variable would be better named `$queryRan`

Comment: please also copy/paste the form code (HTML) as well. So we can see where `submit2` is coming from. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that since your query has no errors in it, `mysqli_query` will return true every time you run the query, *even if there are no rows to delete*. What you need to do is check if any rows were deleted using [`mysqli_affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) instead:

```
if($payment == $method) {
    echo "Please contact the company";
} 
else if (mysqli_affected_rows($link) > 0) {                                       
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you already run the SQL even before proceeding to the condition. As what I've noticed

> $run_query = mysqli_query($link,$sql) // This was already executed before it execute the if statement and just assign its result to $run_query variable.

Try revising code your code with this one

```
if (isset($_POST["submit2"])) {
    $uid = $_SESSION["uid"];
    $remove_id = $_POST["remove_id"];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM orders WHERE product_id = '$remove_id' AND user_id = '$uid'";
    $payment = $_POST["p_status"];
    $method = "Paypal";
    if ( $payment == $method ) { // It will check first if condition is true
        echo "Please contact the company";
    } else if ( mysqli_query($link,$sql) ) { // It will be executed it the condition is false.                                  
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)